# Asp.net Mvc RedirectToAction not redirecting within account controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirecttoaction

In my **Global.asax** file I have an event  **Session_OnEnd** which is fired when session timeout expires. Below is the code in Global.asax

```
protected void Session_OnEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Controllers.AccountController obj = new 
             Controllers.AccountController();
        obj.RedirectoLogin();
}
```

Code in Account Controller

```
 internal void RedirectoLogin()
 {
        ViewBag.Message = "Session Expired";
        RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
 }

 [AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
 {
   ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
   return View();
 }
```

Method gets called . But doesn't get redirected to Login page.

Comment: You really shouldn't need to do this. If the session has ended and user is no longer authorised, the next request they make to a secured item should automatically redirect them to the designated login page.

Answer (score 0):

The `Session_OnEnd()` method, gets called within the ASP.Net framework, on the server side. Since HTTP is stateless, the server cannot enforce a user to redirect to a new page (the connection is probably long-closed).

This method is intended to perform some clean-up (e.g. remove a database record for online users).

Further to @DavidG's comment, if you want to redirect the user, on the next request (when the browser sends the - now expired - session cookie) the user will be redirected to the login page.

If your web application relies heavily on client-side logic, a client-side timer that matches the session duration on the server, can trigger a redirect once the session has expired.